# Uniform Cone Condition with Unit Normal Vector

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I was going through this article from M. BRAMSON, K. BURDZY AND W. KENDALL
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1362750941
where the uniform interior cone condition is given this way:

A domain $D$ is said to satisfy a uniform interior cone condition,
based on radius $\delta > 0$ and angle $\alpha \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, if, for every $x \in \partial D$, there is at least one unit vector $m$ such that the cone $C(m) = \{z : \langle z, m \rangle > |z| \cos(\alpha)\}$ satisfies
$$ (y + C(m)) \cap B(x,\delta) \subset D, \qquad \forall y \in D \cap B(x,\delta). $$

Because of the terminology and of the geometric intuition, it seems to me that this definition should be equivalent to the following:

For all $x \in \partial D$, there exists a radius $h$ and an angle $\beta$ such that 
$x + su \in D$ for all $u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, |u \cdot n_x| > \beta$, $s \in (0,h)$, where $n_x$ the inward normal vector at $x$.

I believe the second definition is basically the first one with the choice $m = n_x$ for all $x$, and that this choice can be made at all $x \in \partial D$ if the uniform interior cone condition in the sense of the first definition holds.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: In your definition, you are just checking that $(y+C(m))\cap B(x,\delta)\subset D$ for $y=x$, not for every $y\in D\cap B(x,\delta)$. It is certainly (not strictly) weaker. To me, their condition seems equivalent to saying that $\partial D$ is locally a graph of a $\cos(\alpha)$-Lipschitz function, in the direction $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two reasons why the two definitions are different:

1. In your second definition, you use the unit normal vector, which is *not* defined if the domain boundary is not sufficiently smooth. In fact, bounded Lipschitz domains already satisfy a uniform cone condition.
2. Why we call it a *uniform* cone condition is that just one set of parameters $\alpha$ are $\delta$ should work everywhere. Take the planar domain $\{(x,y):x>1,\,0<y<1/x\}$. This would fulfill your second definition but would not satisfy a uniform cone condition.

Comment: 1. Is it possible to have a Lipschitz domain without a unit normal vector ? Or do we just lose uniqueness ? 

2. Your answer suggests that my condition is actually weaker (i.e. satisfied by more domains). Is it actually true ?

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean by a unit vector for non smooth domains, but consider convex domains, and then non-convex domains. One of these might eliminate what you mean by a normal vector. 2. As stated, your condition is neither weaker nor stronger. Your condition is weaker, if you allow arbitrary vector m instead of requiring it to be the normal vector.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring up your old answer but I am very curious whether rectangles and balls satisfy this uniform cone condition.

Comment: @JohnK yes they do